# .Notation Confusion and saving vlaues into properties for later use.

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, object, visual-studio-2017

So I am trying to create a little game where you fight a boss but I don't think I understand how to use the dot notation for object orientated programming for this.

In my main class, I supposedly make the property of defense points in my 'Boss' class equal to 20.

```
  }
    public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // 'Challenge' Button -
    {
        Boss InitializeBoss = new Boss(); // the boss object created should have these values -       
        InitializeBoss.DefensePoints = 20;
  // Boss   ^   ------     ^property
```

The structure of my Boss class is as follows:

```
   class Character
{        
    public int AttackPoints;
    public int DefensePoints { get; set; }
    public virtual void AttackMethod() {
        AttackPoints = 5;
    }
}
```

I first, created a 'Character' class with a couple properties and an attack method (which I override in the boss class for the boss's attack)

```
    class Boss : Character
{
    public int LordStrength
    {          
        set { AttackPoints = 10; }
        get { return AttackPoints; }
    }

    public override void AttackMethod()
    {          
    Random Rnd1 = new Random();
    int LowVar = AttackPoints - 2;
    int HighVar = AttackPoints + 3;
    int SmiteImpact = Rnd1.Next(LowVar, HighVar);
}
```

But since the DefensePoints Property is still available in my MainMethod under my "Program class", I still should be able to create an object out of 'Boss' class and initialize the value of defense points from there?

Problem is, in the next button click (the attack button),

```
   // Calculate Damage - 
        Boss DMeasure = new Boss();
        int damage = DMeasure.DefensePoints - Move.AttackPoints;
        MessageBox.Show(" Defense points left: " + damage);

        ChristStatus GPBoss = new ChristStatus();
```

the damage keeps coming out as wrong value.. 
How am I treating my DefensePoints property incorrectly?

I wouldn't ask for debugging help usually, but perhaps, since this is such a fundamental oop concept, it could qualify as a concept question. Like stupidity could be a virtue in this case, maybe?

Comment: Looks like in your attack button, you are creating a new Boss on each attack. Would you not rather calculate the damage from the InitializeBoss instance?

Comment: Create one single Boss as class field in your form instead of creating bosses as local variables. E.g.: `private readonly Boss _boss = new Boss();`. Also your `LordStrength` property is very strange. No matter which value you assign it, it will set `AttackPoints` to 10 but if you don't assign it a value it will return the original `AttackPoints`.

Comment: @Andrew Grothe  My bad. That initiation in the button 5 click is actually just to start the fight. I was hoping to pass the value of 20 into the defense property of the 'Character' (and consequently, the Boss class) but when I use the other button click, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes I thought I was able to set it originally at 10 attack points. Then when I actually call the method from the Boss class, it overrides and runs that little rnd.next calculation to create some "randomness" in the Boss's attack strength.

Comment: So that first little bit runs every time a player wishes to initiate a fight with the boss. I have HP and stuff. I just wanted to initiate defensepoints from the main method make sure I understood how to set properties of different values from the main like that I guess It's more practice than anything.